# Conditional probability in birth

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose that there are two endangered species of polar bear. The only difference between the species is in the probability of giving birth to twins. Species X gives birth to twins 10% of the time, otherwise giving birth to a single cub. Species Y gives birth to twins 20% of the time, otherwise giving birth to a single cub. Suppose that you are working for a captive breeding program. You have a new female bear of unknown species. She just gave birth to twins. What is the probability that her next birth will also be twins?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Note:  you need a prior for the distribution of the two sub-species.  Are the two equally numerous?  You can guess at $\frac 12$ for each but this really should be specified.  You also need to assume something about successive births...I suppose that independence isn't too bad a guess there.

Comment: This question is exactly the same as: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789615/conditional-probability-birth-prediction. Because that is an unanswered question, the system does not allow me to flag as duplicate. Rather than creating a new account just to ask the exact same question, focus on improving your old question by adding what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer this question. It depends on the relative proportions of Species X and Species Y. If almost all polar bears are Species X, the the probability that the next birth will be twins will be close to $10\%$, but if almost all polar bears are Species Y, then the probability that the next birth will be twins will be close to $20\%$.

If we assume that the relative frequencies of species X and Y are $p$ and $1-p$, respectively, then we can answer the question in terms of $p$. Indeed, in that case, the probability that the bear is Species X is equal to $\frac{.1p}{.1p+.2(1-p)}=\frac{p}{2-p}$, and the probability that the bear is Species Y is equal to $\frac{2-2p}{2-p}$. Then, the probability that the next birth will be twins is equal to $.1$ times the first of those probabilities, plus $.2$ times the second one, which comes out to $$\frac{4-3p}{20-10p}.$$